# Review of (free) budget travel apps

Tags: budget, planning, mobile-apps, software

I usually control my costs of travelling with a spreadsheet.
Recently I have started using an app and I am really enjoying it. It's much easier to do: it does currency conversion, adds the location automatically, categorization, it's really great.

However, it's not free. It's not expensive either, but it's based on a subscription fee, and at this point I am not interested in adding yet another subscription-based service to my life. I am not happy with the fact that I am locked to a vendor either. They allow exporting information, but under specific conditions.

I am looking for an app, preferably free, that allows me to export data.
I am ok with buying the app, if needed. But I am not interestedd in subscriptions.

I have looked for reviews, but these are not very systematic or lack detail.
Are there any good resources comparing budget apps for travelling?

Comment: What's the app you use? I occasionally use Splitwise. Like @vince's app, designed to split expenses, but should also work for just yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Tricount](https://www.tricount.com/en/) for a while. I like how simple it is, especially as it works offline. It is designed to share expenses but it would also work if you are on your own.

The part where you add your expenses is free, but exporting is a premium feature. And they mostly work as a subscription-based service. But, they also, once in a while in the app, offer the possibility to only make your current trip premium, for a one-time fee (around 1-2 euro).

If you cannot get this one-time payment for premium features, you may as well pay the subscription only for one month, when you want the numbers (assuming you don't travel forever or you don't need the precise accountancy number every month).